# Kill child process when parent process exits in C

Tags: c, multithreading, fork, parent-child

I am trying to create a program where it performs some task and exits. however, I want to exit from the program if the user enters some string on the terminal.

The way I thought to solve it:
Create a parent process where it is performing the main task. the main task has a loop. 
create a child process where it is waiting for an input from the user. if the user inputs the exit string, the child process will update a variable and kills itself. The loop in the parent process will check for the value of the variable, if that value is changed by the child process, it will also exit. If the user doesn't input the exit string, the parent process will complete the task and kills itself. at this moment I want to kill the child process also.
How can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for saying what you are actually trying to accomplish here.

You may find it much easier to create a single multithreaded process rather than create two single threaded processes.

1. Thread #1 does work in a loop and periodically checks a variable `exit_flag`.  If the variable is set, then it calls `exit`.  If it finishes the work, it calls `exit`.
2. Thread #2 waits for input from the user.  If it gets input, it sets the variable `exit_flag`.

This way, when you call `exit`, both threads will automatically exit.  You will either need to use a mutex/semaphore or another kind of synchronization, e.g., if you have `libatomic-ops`:

```
#include "atomic_ops.h"

AO_t exit_flag;

// In thread #2
AO_store(&exit_flag, 1);

// In thread #1
while (!AO_load(&exit_flag)) {
    ...
}
```

**Warning about the above code:** Setting a global flag only works this way because the main thread *only* reads the global flag and *nothing else.*  If you need to send more than one word between threads you'll need some kind of synchronization mechanism, e.g., a mutex, semaphore, or `AO_store_release` paired with `AO_store_acquire`.

**If you use processes instead of threads:** Since processes don't share mutable memory by default, it is not as easy as "updating a variable".  Each process has its own set of private variables.  You would need to set up a region of shared memory or communicate some other way (e.g., signal, pipe, socket) which is extra work for you.

## Full example

Here is a quick full example.  The main thread does "work" that involves counting down from 5.  When it reaches 0, it exits and prints a message.  The second thread reads user input, when it reads a line starting with `'e'` it sets a flag which causes the main thread to exit.

The second thread is created as a *detached* thread only because we do not need to join with it.  It does not affect the correctness of this particular program.

If you call `exit`, **all** threads in your program should be terminated, unless there is something wrong with your platform.

**Note:** This example requires `libatomic-ops` and assumes you are using POSIX threads.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <atomic_ops.h>
#include <errno.h>

static AO_t exit_flag;

#define fail(x) fail_func(x, __LINE__)

static void fail_func(int code, int line)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "line %d: failed with code %d\n", line, code);
    abort();
}

static void *input_thread(void *param)
{
    char buf[16], *p;
    (void) param;
    while (1) {
        p = fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin);
        if (!p)
            break;
        if (buf[0] == 'e')
            break;
        else
            puts("unknown command");
    }
    AO_store(&exit_flag, 1);
    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pthread_attr_t attr;
    pthread_t thread2;
    int r, c;
    struct timespec t;
    t.tv_sec = 1;
    t.tv_nsec = 0;
    r = pthread_attr_init(&attr);
    if (r) fail(r);
    // Note: making the thread detached is not actually necessary.
    r = pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);
    if (r) fail(r);
    r = pthread_create(&thread2, &attr, input_thread, NULL);
    if (r) fail(r);
    c = 5;
    while (1) {
        if (AO_load(&exit_flag)) {
            puts("thread 1 exiting (canceled)");
            exit(1);
        }
        printf("counter = %d\n", c);
        if (c == 0) {
            puts("thread 1 exiting (finished)");
            exit(0);
        }
        c--;
        r = nanosleep(&t, NULL);
        if (r) fail(errno);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Sample output (user input is in **bold**):

```
$ ./a.out
counter = 5
counter = 4
counter = 3
counter = 2
counter = 1
counter = 0
thread 1 exiting (finished)
$ ./a.out
counter = 5
counter = 4
exit
thread 1 exiting (canceled)
```

Comment: How can I kill Thread #2 when the Thread #1 has finished doing its job?

Comment: "when you call `exit`, both threads will automatically exit."  Calling `exit` will terminate the process, including all of its threads.

Comment: Mutex is not overkill; it's essential for well-defined behavior. But you could instead use a semaphore and just `sem_trywait` to see if it's been posted. That's easier.

Comment: @R..: A mutex is not necessary here.  The only guarantee you need is that thread 1 only reads a nonzero value if thread 2 has written it.  We need no ordering constraints on the loads and stores and we have no requirements for data consistency.  A mutex adds no value, neither does a semaphore.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: There is no guarantee that one thread will **ever** see the write performed by the other thread unless there's some sort of synchronization primitive. It could eternally read 0.

Comment: @R..: Isn't that platform dependent?  For instance, the strong cache-coherency protocols for x86 would make the write visible to all threads ... i.e., every write has store-release semantics.  On other platforms with weaker memory models though I could see where a memory barrier of some type may be needed to force other processors to invalidate any locally stored copies of the variable in cache ...

Comment: This question is about C, not about implementation-details of one CPU architecture.

Comment: @R..: Aren't architectures without eventual consistency fairly esoteric, i.e., you would know if you had one?  The implementation details are important, since the C specification doesn't tell us anything about threads.

Comment: Basically the only arch with automatic consistency is x86. I would suspect most others have the sort of "eventual consistency" you're probably referring to if you allow for other processes running and eventually evicting the stale pages from the cpu cache, but on a low-load machine without any contention for cpu cores, this could be on the order of minutes or hours...

Comment: @R..: Okay, you're right that you often need memory synchronization, although there are several other architectures with eventual consistency besides x86.  I think the unique thing about x86 is the memory order guarantees it provides.  (You can peek in the `libatomic-ops` source code to look for inclusions of `"atomic_load_store.h"` from files in the `sysdeps` directory, it looks like about half the architectures supported require no synchronization for simple loads/stores.)

Comment: Are you sure those archs even support SMP? Sometimes the reason synchronization looks trivial is that only UP is supported. For example most ARMs are not capable of supporting SMP due to lacking proper atomic ops and the need for kernel help (which only works on UP) emulating atomic CAS...

Comment: Hm, it appears architectures with atomic loads/stores implemented in plain C include s390, Alpha, MIPS, x86, PowerPC, M68k, ARM, HPPA, and SPARC.  I think all of those support SMP (there are definitely SMP ARMs floating around).  (It also includes AVR, but I've never heard of SMP AVR.)  Some of the architectures are atomic for any load/store of any addressable operand, some are only atomic for aligned operands of certain widths.  Of course, 99% of the time atomic loads and stores are entirely useless.

Comment: I am still unable to get it work. I called exit from the main and still thread #1 is waiting for the user input. only after I enter something, the program ends.
can u please create a small program to demonstrate how it is done?
Thanks

Comment: @RiteshBanka: If you call `exit` and your process does not exit, something is wrong.  I have added an example.

Comment: The problem is not the atomic nature of an individual load/store operation to a memory address, but rather that a store will synchronize with another load on a separate CPU thread (i.e., the load operation, even though it takes place after the store operation, will not see the effects of the store).  That is a memory consistency guarantee that certain platforms make (x86, SPARC) and others do not (ARM, PPC, etc.).

Comment: @Jason: Can you provide a source for this?  From "The PowerPC Virtual Environment Architecture" section 1.2, "aggressive implementations of the architecture can permit intervals of time during which different copies of a storage location have different values".  The use of the word "interval" means to me that the cache will eventually become consistent without special effort by the programmer.  All of the wording for `sync` et al. seem to imply that they just affect the ordering of the loads and stores, not whether they are visible to other processors in the first place.  I'm not sure.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: Yes, the values will eventually become synced by the hardware (at least on platforms like PPC), but there is no guarantee made for when that will happen, and I think that's the primary point being made.  Additionally, because of weaker memory ordering of these platforms, just because the value becomes visible doesn't mean that it wasn't re-ordered, so that what you've assumed has taken place because the value was written to actually hasn't (i.e., the store actually came before an operation it would have seemed from a sequential execution of the code it should have come after).

Comment: @Jason: But that's exactly my point: we have no ordering requirements at all.  Our only real requirement for correctness is that **if** the main thread reads 1 **then** the user must have sent an exit command.  Since the input thread is doing no other work (from the viewpoint of the main thread), there is no possible ordering that causes incorrect behavior (in fact, there is only one possible ordering, since the second thread only does one operation on shared memory, at least in user space).

Comment: @DietrichEpp: You're definitely right in this situation ... but R has a point in that using global flags from threads really requires a synchronization primitive on weakly ordered memory platforms in order to ensure correctness in more general cases.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `atexit()` to run a cleanup function when the main process exits.

However, processes (assuming you are talking POSIX and classical processes) do not share data with their children, therefore the change of your flag variable will not be visible in the parent.

A much cleaner solution would be to either just use the system provided interaction (namely, the user pressing Ctrl+C, which will cause the tty to send a `SIGINT` to the session leader (the foreground process), which you can trap to cleanly exit) or check for user input using `select()/poll()` in the main application.

Answer (score 2):

When you fork the child, the parent process will receive the process ID of the child.  You can send a `SIGTERM` signal to the child via the `kill()` function if you wanted it terminated on-demand.  Make sure though to call `wait()` after sending the `SIGTERM` signal in order to prevent the child-process from becoming a "zombie" process.

If all you want to do though is get a user-input string back from a child-process, you could simply use `popen` and `cat` to start up a child process that will, using `cat`, echo back whatever the user inputs on the command-line.  In order to avoid blocking on the read to the stream created from pipe, you can get the file-descriptor associated with the stream using `fileno()`, and then use `poll` or `select` with a timeout value.  When the parent is done, or sees the termiation string input from the user, it then simply calls `pclose()` and that will terminate the `cat` process.